# ActiveMQ Monitor tool with Email Alerts

Tags: activemq-classic, monitor

I would like to know the open source tools which can be used to monitor ActiveMQ performance like

1. Whether it is able to accept new Messages
2. Is there any piled queue
3. Messages from queue are getting processed or not

Send Email alerts to the recipient if any one of the above is not working.

FYI, we are having issues with ActiveMQ which will not accept any incoming New Messages but acts like up and running without any issues.

I am using Web Console to see the queue status, but it won't denote whether it is able to accept new Messages or not. Also there is no Email alert mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an off-the-shelf solution, but it may be a starting point for you to build up your own tool.  You can set up a background process to monitor the health of the queues, and then define your own custom actions when it exceeds your defined threshold settings.

[Parsing Statistics to Check on Queue Health](http://austgate.co.uk/2013/01/parsing-activemq-statistics-to-check-on-queue-health/)

[Some sample monitoring scripts](https://github.com/ripienaar/monitoring-scripts/tree/master/activemq)

Comment: For some reason, somebody downvoted my answer as "Not useful" without bothering to provide an alternative answer. That downvote is "not useful". The link I provided is directly related to the question that was asked, namely the sample monitory scripts are: 1) open source, and 2) monitors ActiveMQ performance of how many messages are in a queue.  How is my answer not useful? I think someone may be destructively downvoting answers. It's unfortunate that this can be done anonymously.